# Does Google Chrome Frame require administration privileges to install?

Tags: windows, privileges

I have a customer of a customer complaining that the app the company I work for created doesn't work on Internet Explorer. Our customer is all using Google Chrome, but apparently the customer of the customer is forbidden to use any other browser that Internet Explorer.

I don't know what version of Internet Explorer or Windows they are using and getting this information is turning out to be hard, so I'm wondering, can't I just prompt them to install Google Chrome Frame? Does that require administrator privileges on the machine (they are likely not to have them).

Thanks.

NOTE: around here we just use macs; and I don't know much about Windows so I'm shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember seeing a recent news release saying it's not stable and they're working on being able to install without admin priviledges, so yes, you probably need them for now...

Comment: The current release (as of September 22) is stable but admin privileges are still required for installation.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an admin-free installation:

> http://techcrunch.com/2011/05/10/google-chrome-frame-ie-admin/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Administrator rights are required but they're working to have this issue resolved in the future.

From the [Chromium blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/09/google-chrome-frame-stable-and-speedy.html) (Posted on yesterday on September 22):

- We’re working on making start-up speed even faster **and removing the current requirement for administrator rights to install the plug-in**.